# How to parse json file using the previous key?

Tags: python, json

I have long JSON like this (I need to find the number of barracks destroyed by each team):

```
[{'player_slot': 129,
  'slot': 6,
  'team': 3,
  'time': 2117.449,
  'type': 'CHAT_MESSAGE_TOWER_KILL'},
 {'player_slot': 132,
  'slot': 9,
  'team': 3,
  'time': 2156.047,
  'type': 'CHAT_MESSAGE_TOWER_KILL'},
 {'key': '512', 'time': 2178.992, 'type': 'CHAT_MESSAGE_BARRACKS_KILL'},
 {'player_slot': 4,
  'slot': 4,
  'team': 2,
  'time': 2326.829,
  'type': 'CHAT_MESSAGE_TOWER_KILL'},
{'key': '2', 'time': 2333.384, 'type': 'CHAT_MESSAGE_BARRACKS_KILL'}],
 {'key': '2', 'time': 2340.384, 'type': 'CHAT_MESSAGE_BARRACKS_KILL'}]

radiant_barracks_kills = 0
dire_barracks_kills = 0
for objective in match['objectives']:
    for i,e in enumerate(objective):
        if e['type'] == 'CHAT_MESSAGE_BARRACKS_KILL':
            if objective[i-1]['slot'] < 5:
                radiant_barracks_kills += 1
            if objective[i-1]['slot'] >= 5:
                dire_barracks_kills += 1

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

It is necessary to run in the cycle all such lists of dictionaries and determine the number of barracks destroyed for each team.

Comment: It is a bit unclear. What is `match['objectives']`?

Comment: 'match' it is a json file, match['objectives'] contains the list of dictionaries

Comment: So `match['objectives']` would be the list of dicts at the top. You have 2 closing `]` on your sample data, are there really 2 consecutive `{'key': '2', 'time': 2340.384, 'type': 'CHAT_MESSAGE_BARRACKS_KILL'}]` at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that, as you said, "*match['objectives'] contains the list of dictionaries*", then your problem is that you made an extra iteration. If your tried to `print` the type and value of `e`:

```
for objective in match['objectives']:
    for i,e in enumerate(objective):
        print(type(e), e)
```

You would get:

```
<class 'str'> player_slot
<class 'str'> slot
<class 'str'> team
<class 'str'> time
<class 'str'> type
<class 'str'> player_slot
<class 'str'> slot
<class 'str'> team
<class 'str'> time
<class 'str'> type
...
```

The 1st `for` loop is already iterating over the list of dictionaries. So `objective` would already be a dictionary. When you did the 2nd `for` loop to `enumerate`, it would then iterate over the *keys* of the dictionary, and then `e['type']` would fail because it's as if you did:

```
"player_slot"['type']
```

which would result in "*TypeError: string indices must be integers*".

You just need to iterate once.

```
radiant_barracks_kills = 0
dire_barracks_kills = 0
list_of_objectives = match['objectives']  # [{..},{..},..{..}]

for i, objective in enumerate(list_of_objectives):
    # objective is a dict
    if objective['type'] == 'CHAT_MESSAGE_BARRACKS_KILL':
        if list_of_objectives[i-1]['slot'] < 5:
            radiant_barracks_kills += 1
        if list_of_objectives[i-1]['slot'] >= 5:
            dire_barracks_kills += 1
```